# Why is my Scroll event being called twice here?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener

[image]

**InfiniteScrollFactory:**

```
const scrollingSocial = (e) => {
    console.log('scrollingSocial');
    // e.stopPropagation();
    const reachedBottom = () => socialCol.scrollHeight - socialCol.scrollTop === socialCol.offsetHeight;
    const loadMoreItems = () => {
        console.log('[ Fire Once ] loadMoreItems...');
        $rootScope.$emit("socialmedia.stream.load");
    };
    if (reachedBottom()) loadMoreItems();
};

const wireSocialScroll = (list) => {
    console.log('wireSocialScroll called!');
    if (notEmpty(list)) {
        socialCol.addEventListener('scroll', scrollingSocial);
    }
};

const attachScrollListener = (location, col, list) => {
    console.log('attachScrollListener');
    console.log(' location', location);
    switch (location) {
        // case 'tagsPanel'   : tagsCol   = col; wireTagsScroll(list);   break;
        // case 'feedPanel'   : feedCol   = col; wireFeedScroll(list);   break;
        case 'socialMedia' : socialCol = col; wireSocialScroll(list); break;
    }
};
```

My `scrollingSocial` function gets called once when I scroll down the mouse once. It takes about 45 'scrolls' to finally trigger my `loadMoreItems` function. However then it gets called twice. And I see the scroll the 46th time even though I did not scroll a 46th time.

**socialMediaDirective:**

```
const getColHeight = (tags) => {
    if (notEmpty(tags)) InfiniteScrollFactory.attachScrollListener('socialMedia', socialCol, tags);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling and it's event triggers can be a bit finicky.

Just using this code:

```
$(document).on('scroll', () => console.log('scroll'));
```

I get multiple scrolls each time I tick my mouse wheel, no matter how carefully I do so.

It's probably the same sort of issue with what you have. What you'll want to do is simply add a boolean that keeps track of if you've called `loadMoreItems`, use that boolean to keep it from calling it again.

```
let loadingMoreItems = false;
const scrollingSocial = (e) => {
    console.log('scrollingSocial');
    // e.stopPropagation();
    const reachedBottom = () => socialCol.scrollHeight - socialCol.scrollTop === socialCol.offsetHeight;
    const loadMoreItems = () => {
        console.log('[ Fire Once ] loadMoreItems...');
        $rootScope.$emit("socialmedia.stream.load");
    };
    if (!loadingMoreItems && reachedBottom()) {
        loadingMoreItems = true;
        loadMoreItems();
    }
};
```

Then, at an appropriate time (or times), change that boolean back to false to allow it to call again (scrolling back up, more items loaded, `reachedBottom()` resulting in false once, etc).

Comment: Ah thanks! I had searched and found out I had asked this same question years ago lol, the fix at that time was a `timeout`, however the timeout didn't work. This check does however!